# React app background behavior in smartphone mode

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a simple business card website in ReactJS and I wanted to paint over the background. To do this, I made changes to the App.css file:

```
.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  color: #222222;
  background-color: #E8E4E1;
}
```

In normal mode, everything works fine, but if I turn on smartphone mode, I see this

[image]

The modal window doesn't open correctly either.

[image]

I am using Google Chrome. I did not change anything globally in the standard project settings. I have absolutely no idea what's going on. I will be grateful for any help

This is the component code that is causing the error.

```
const AboutMe = () => {
    function AboutMePicture() {
        return <img src={picture} className="aboutMePicture"/>
    }

    return (
        <div className="aboutMeMain">
            <div className="paragraphTitle">О себе</div>
            <div className="aboutMeBlock">
                <div className="aboutMeLeft">
                    <div className="aboutMeText">
                        ...something text
                    </div>
                    <div className="aboutMeText">
                        ...something text
                    </div>
                    <div className="aboutMeText">
                        ...something text
                    </div>
                    <div className="aboutMeText">
                        ...something text
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="aboutMeRight">
                    <AboutMePicture/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default AboutMe;
```

And styles:

```
.paragraphTitle {
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.aboutMeMain {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 55%;
    min-width: 530px;

}

.aboutMeBlock {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #b2aba4;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 20px 30px 5px 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aboutMePicture {
    width: 200px;
}

.aboutMeLeft {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.aboutMeRight {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.aboutMeText {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: It looks like if you were using `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` for the children

Comment: Yes, but it was necessary. Now I can't put the background back in place?

Comment: It wasn't necessary. You probably can, but you made things harder

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong. I left only one component, which definitely does not use positioning, but the problem still persists. I added the code for this component to the question and ask you to see if you can see what's wrong.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you remove images?

Comment: No, it wasn't the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was the minimum width of the elements.

```
min-width: 530px
```

At the same time, the width of the smartphone does not exceed 400px and the device has to rescale to fit the image. As a result of changing the scale, the background decreases and moves out to the upper left corner.

Problem solved by adding:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .myProjectMain {
        width: 90%;
        min-width: 350px;
    }
}
```